# RSpec Cookbook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Just learning RSpec and trying to do some tutorials. In one of the tutorials the  criteria below has been provided. I am to write the test and code to make it pass. I am just learning Ruby and RSpec. Where do I find a 'cookbook' for writing the RSpec tests according to the type of spec?

The specs:

```
A person should save correctly
A person should have many addresses
A person's address must have a street, city, and zip
A person's address can have an optional country
If the 'country' is left blank, it should default to 'USA' prior to saving
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Updated April 2014: The first two references are effectively dead and have been unlinked The original links are still available in the markdown in case they come back to life.]*

- <s>RSpec and models</s> (dead link)
- <s>RSpec and controllers</s> (returns 'I shouldn't have access to this page.')
- [All the RailsCasts touching on RSpec](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rspec)

Those should be more than enough to cover the tests you list; probably the model one is plenty. I'm wary of "person should save correctly", since that's actually testing Rails.

Comment: But skip controller specs -- they don't test what you actually care about -- and use Cucumber instead.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Depends--high-level behavior is fine to test; the view layer depends on the controller, but has different characteristics.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the second half of your sentence. But if I understand it correctly, it doesn't matter; in Rails, neither the view nor the controller should be tested in isolation. View and controller specs are both painful to write and a waste of effort -- because they test implementation, not behavior. Controller specs are occasionally useful for testing non-user-facing APIs, but that's about it, and even there I think Cucumber often does a better job. RSpec is only useful at the model level.